# Não consigo reutilizar método em classe filho

Tags: java, eclipse

Criei uma classe `ContaCorrente` como filha de uma classe `Conta`.

Na classe `Conta` tenho um método `saca`:

```
public boolean saca (double valor) {

    if (saldo >= valor) {

        this.saldo -= valor;
        System.out.println("Operação concluída, seu saldo é: "+ saldo);
        return true;
    } else {

        System.out.println("Seu saldo é insuficiente para essa operação");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Preciso criar na classe filha uma regra um pouco diferente, porém reutilizando esse método da classe pai.

Porém quando digito `conta` ou `saca` e aperto <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>espaço</kbd> para o Eclipse me sugerir o `Override` do método, não funciona, não aparece nenhum `Override`. O que estou fazendo errado?

CLASSES COMPLETAS:

```
class Conta {
    private Cliente titular;
    private int AG;
    private int CC;
    private double saldo;
    private static int total;

    public Conta(int AG, int CC) {

        Conta.total ++;
        this.AG = AG;
        this.CC = CC;
        System.out.println("A conta foi criada com sucesso");
        System.out.println("Agência: "+ AG);
        System.out.println("Conta: " + CC);
    }

    public void deposita (double valor) {

        this.saldo += valor;
    }

    public boolean saca (double valor) {

        if (saldo >= valor) {

            this.saldo -= valor;
            System.out.println("Operação concluída, seu saldo é: "+ saldo);
            return true;
        } else {

            System.out.println("Seu saldo é insuficiente para essa operação");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean transfere (double valor, Conta destino) {

        if(this.saldo >= valor) {

            this.saldo -= valor;

            destino.saldo += valor;

            System.out.println("Transação realizada com sucesso, seu novo saldo é: " + this.saldo);
            return true;
        } else {

            System.out.println("Transaão NÃO efetuada, saldo insuficiente!");
            return false;
        }                           

    }

    public double getSaldo() {

        return this.saldo;
    }

    public int getCC() {

        return this.CC;
    }

    public void setCC (int numeroCC) {

         CC = numeroCC;
    }

    public int getAG () {

        return this.AG;
    }

    public void setAG (int numeroAG) {

        AG = numeroAG;
    }

    public Cliente getTitular() {
        return titular;
    }

    public void setTitular(Cliente titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }

    public static int getTotal () {

        return Conta.total;
    }
}
```

FILHA:

```
public class ContaCorrente extends Conta {
    public ContaCorrente (int AG, int CC) {
        super(AG, CC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste suas classes completas.

Comment: Se vc digitar "saca" e Ctrl+espaço, aí não vai? "conta" não vai funcionar porque o overwrite é no método, não na classe...

Comment: mesmo digitando saca e Ctrl+espaço tbm não está indo :/

Comment: pra poder dar override a classe precisa ser abstrata não?

Comment: Acho que não, no exercício as classes estão com definições certas

Comment: Cria o método na classe filha e veja se funciona. Pode ser algo com o auto complete.

Comment: Agradeço aos que tentaram ajudar, mas vou fechar a pergunta... já vieram 3 pessoas editar a pergunta, uma editando o que a outra ja editou... aparentemente as pessoas estão mais preocupadas em aparecer do que realmente ajudar...

Obrigada aos 3 que tentaram me ajudar.

Comment: Diego, eu tentei criar manualmente o método na filha, mas quando coloco o @Overrride, da erro de compilação :/

Comment: realmente não precisa ser abstract, testei aqui suas classes igual ao que tá e tá funcionando sim...deve ser algo do IDE mesmo

Comment: @JujubaDev Editar a pergunta não tem nada a ver com "querer aparecer". O site é colaborativo e editar faz parte da melhoria contínua do conteúdo. Leia [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) para saber mais

Comment: Ambas as classes estão no mesmo pacote?

Comment: Estão sim Diego...

Comment: Se estivesse em outro pacote você teria problema pq não definiu o modificador public na classe Conta. Experimenta colocar o public na classe conta mesmo assim.

Comment: Sim imaginei, mas conferi agora e estão todas as classes no mesmo pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que você está tentando acessar o atributo `saldo` da classe mãe `Conta`. Mas, pensando em orientação a objetos e visibilidade, estes atributos só poderão ser acessados pela própria classe, já que eles são `private`. Para alterar isso, você terá que colocá-los como `protected` (para permitir acesso da própria classe e classes filhas)

Assim:

`protected double saldo;` (na classe `Conta`)

Agora você poderá gerar um método `@Override`, mas caso não apareça a opção de gerar, basta fazer manualmente (na classe `ContaCorrente`):

```
@Override
public boolean saca(double valor) {
    if (saldo >= valor) {

        this.saldo -= valor;
        System.out.println("Operação concluída, seu saldo é: " + saldo);
        return true;
    } else {

        System.out.println("Seu saldo é insuficiente para essa operação");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106404/discussion-on-answer-by-lucas-bittencourt-nao-consigo-reutilizar-metodo-em-class)